# How to delete end of String in CSV file shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file that has over 10,000 entries called csv1.csv that I need to manipulate. I want to change the 11th column all the values which contain the email addresses of different people. 
What I have right now in column 11:

E-mail Address

```
Hi@yahoo.com
What@yahoo.com
Up@yahoo.com
lol@yahoo.com
```

Desired output:

```
Hi
What
Up
lol
```

I also want to keep all other 12 columns the same and use redirect > to put in another csv file. So essentially only taking out the @yahoo.com, but keeping whatever is in front of the string. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: PS. @yahoo.com is just an example, but they all have the same email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can modify any particular column like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/@.+/, "", $11)} 1' file.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: I just realized this also takes away all of the commas that separate the values in the file. It is supposed to just take out the "@yahoo.com" right?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
    cat csv1.csv | awk '{print $11}' | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'
```